# How do I get value after selected from dropdown menu with Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I want the last value from this dropdown menu.

```
<select id="VersionValue">
  <option value="0">Select Version</option>
  <option value="1110.0">1110.0</option>
  <option value="1111.0">1111.0</option>
  <option value="1112.0">1112.0</option>
  <option value="1113.0">1113.0</option>
  <option value="1114.0">1114.0</option>
</select>
```

My code in python to get last dropdown menu

```
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("VersionValue"))
    selectLen = len(select.options)
    select.select_by_index(selectLen - 1)
```

How do I get value after selected from dropdown menu with Python?
I use selenium library for python.

Comment: What is the problem with what you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [first_selected_option](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.first_selected_option), use it after selecting the value

```
option = select.first_selected_option
```

This will return the webelement of the option. To get the value use

```
option.text
```

Or

```
option.get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: I use this solution and I got error "TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable"

Comment: @Aidento remove the brackets.

Comment: I tried to use "select.first_selected_option" too, I got value is  selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="1231213-123-4bff-12qws1-bdd64a123123", element="qwewd123-qweq-40e3-1223-qwesq23123")>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("VersionValue"))
select.select_by_value("1114.0")
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.